# NestJS backend as a microservice and an API Rest the same time?

Tags: api, nestjs, microservices, gateway

Can a NestJS backend be a microservice and an API Rest as the same time ?

main.ts for a microservice:

```
const microservice = await NestFactory.createMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>(
  AppModule,
  {
    transport: Transport.KAFKA,
    // ...options, client, consumer, etc...
  },
);

await microservice.listen();
```

main.ts for a REST API:

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule)
await app.listen(3000);
```

How to mix use create and createMicroservice in the same main.ts ?
Should I use a Gateway API with the serviceA as microservice and serviceB as REST API ?

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure what you're looking for is a [hybrid application](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/hybrid-application). You create the regular HTTP application with `NestFactory.create()` and then you use `app.connectMicroservice()` to add microservices that should run alongside the HTTP server.

Example from the docs:

```js
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
// microservice #1
const microserviceTcp = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
  transport: Transport.TCP,
  options: {
    port: 3001,
  },
});
// microservice #2
const microserviceRedis = app.connectMicroservice<MicroserviceOptions>({
  transport: Transport.REDIS,
  options: {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 6379,
  },
});

await app.startAllMicroservices();
await app.listen(3001);
```